# making first commit into diffusion git :Phabricator

Tags: phabricator

I am setting up a phabricator server and i am observing the below issue, both from my diffusion repository Status window and the daemons.log file

```
Error updating working copy: Command failed with error #128!
COMMAND
git log --format='%H%x01%P%x01%ct' --all --

STDOUT
(empty)

STDRR
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
```

After reading on this issue, i figured out that this is a common issue with bare repositories without first commits. So i tried committing from my local system through repository http URI, but it is returning a 500 exception.
below is the error message i pulled out from phabricator database:

```
 $ select * from phabricator_repository.repository_pullevent;
 500 | {"response.message":"Error 1: sudo: a password is required\n"}
```

Can any one help me out to understand the issues from repository_pullevents and daemons.log file.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved the problem with sudo, by changing the user running apache and adding the symlink created for git-http-backened in sudoers for the apache user.

and the problem with repository bad HEAD revision was resolved by making the first commit from a client machine.